# is android 5.1 on a smartwatch wear compatible?

Tags: wear-os

The KW88 smartwatch is equipped with Android 5.1
Does this mean that this is compatible with android Wear ?
Or do you have to have Android Wear operating system on the smartwatch ?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't say Android **Wear**, it isn't Android Wear. Lots of low-end watches are running some build of Android, but Wear is being pretty tightly controlled by Google (they don't even pretend that it's open-source), so you really only find it on major-brand smartwatches.

Comment: Thanks String : but the KW88 is not just a low end watch, and I wonder if Android 5.1 is not the full android, whereas Wear is only a spin-off to have a smaller core running on a smartwatch, and possibly lower power. I am hoping to reach some-one from google that can explain differences in detail, and someone who can tell from experience if you can use Android studio - selection wear - to develop for this watch.

Comment: It's actually more the other way around; Wear is full Android plus some wearable-specific extensions, like watch faces. A project built from Android Studio for Wear may install, and might even run, on a device without those extensions - but it won't have access to the Wear APIs, because they don't exist on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of this, and i agree. It's an Android 5.1 "adapted". It's possible do anything like a cell phone, BUT, few apps doesn't support the screen configuration and many things simply you can't see or touch... But you can download apps to solve this problems. For example, in Playstore you can navigate, download but you can't go back. Solution? install one app to get a back button on the screen...